# Some questions about interfaces

Tags: java, ssl, interface

question 1:

if SSLSocketFactory is an interface, then what does it mean by

```
     " private static SSLSocketFactory TRUSTED_FACTORY;" ?
```

what is TRUSTED_FACTORY? An interface instance?

question 2:

```
  final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
      return new X509Certificate[0];
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
      // Intentionally left blank
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
      // Intentionally left blank
    }
  } };
```

TrustManager is javax.net.ssl.TrustManager , and X509TrustManager is javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager.I know X509TrustManager is an child-interface of TrustManager, Why can we Instantiate an interface using keyword "new"? And , what's the meaning by declare some functions like getAcceptedIssuers/checkClientTrusted when instantiate this interface?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html -> This is a basic feature of Java that any beginner's book covers, as does the tutorial linked.

Comment: You need to be aware that what this code actually does is radically insecure and should not be used in production code.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to question #1:  If SSLSocketFactory is an interface, then `TRUSTED_FACTORY` is a reference to an object which is an instance of a class (not an interface) that implements the SSLSocketFactory interface.

Answer to question #2:  This code is creating an instance of an anonymous class (not an interface) which implements the X509TrustManager interface.  Java allows you to declare anonymous classes inside another Java class.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html.   As with all implementations of interfaces, you are required to provide an implementation of all methods in the interface (checkClientTrusted, checkServerTrusted, and getAcceptedIssuers), but could also add new methods if needed.